# Setting links to NOT open in iFrames...?

Tags: http, x-frame-options

(This is an unanswered question I asked a few days ago. It was closed because it was thought to be unclear. I updated the question and messaged the mods, but it remains closed so I'm asking again. Sorry about the redundancy.)

I am hosting a webpage created using Dreamweaver CS6 via Apache. When certain links are clicked, they will not load. Inspecting element in Chrome reveals the following error for one of the non-working links:

Refused to display 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yA-Eb_PD4SQ' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

Interestingly, if one right clicks and opens the link in a new tab or window, it will load. FYI I know very little about html and CSS.

How to I tell my site or Apache not to open these links in frames so they will work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `target="_top"` in the html href tag to have the link use the top level frame to open.